# How to pass web forms´ parameters with JQuery and Jersey

Tags: jquery, rest, jersey

My problem is that I have a web form and I want to send this data to a Jersey `restFULL` Method.

in my Javascript I have this call:

```
 console.log('Sending event creation ---> '+eventInJsonString);
$.ajax({
    url: "/Bxip/rest/events/",
//  dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: eventInJsonString,
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success ", data.response);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("error ", data.error);
    }
});
```

My jersey method is:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
//Retornará HTTP_STATUS 204 (on success)
public String addEvent(
        @FormParam("title") String title,
        @FormParam("fechaInicio") String fechaInicio,
        @FormParam("lugar") String lugar,
        @FormParam("categoria") String categoria,
        @FormParam("description") String description,
        @FormParam("fechaFin") String fechaFin) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("ENTRAAA    = " + title + description);
```

And the result before sending the data:

```
 Sending event creation ---> {"title":"aaaa","description":"        aaaaa","fechaInicio":"bbbb","categoria":"Beber y comer","fechaFin":"forever"}
```

But in the Java server side the parameters are null:

```
ENTRAAA    = nullnull
```

How can I send `@POST` to this jersey method from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways to do this. Here you have two possibilities:

- **Using from params**

To receive @FormParam's at Jersey you should send the data url encoded in the body of the post.

The ContentType of the request should be

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and the content of eventInJsonString should be

```
title=aaaa&description=aaaaa&fechaInicio=bbbb&categoria=Beber y comer&fechaFin=forever
```

To process this in Jersey, you should change the @Consumes type to

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
```

This way you will get the @FormParam's filled.

- **Using json**

The problem is that you are trying to send the data in json. If you want to send it that way, you need to change somethings too:

You need to change the request ContentType to

```
application/json
```

and in Jersey you need to change the @Consumes type to

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

If you send it that way, you will also need to remove the @FormParam's from the method:

```
public String addEvent(String jsonBody) throws IOException {

    // Now you need to parse the json to get your parameters...
```

Comment: Perfect answer @nakib, Which method is better if I want to pass an image later?

Comment: I would go with the form params passing the image in base64 as a parameter